# RF: Replacing Escape Chars

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to replace `\` with `/` but due to escape chars Robot Framework is not doing what I was expecting. I am getting the following result:

```
${location1} =    Replace String    C:\Users\bnduch\Downloads    \    /
```

Result:

/C/:/U/s/e/r/s/b/n/d/u/c/h/D/o/w/n/l/o/a/d/s/

How to avoid escape chars here?

Edit:
To get other alternatives i am adding source of my directory string.

In Order to work with downloaded files in IE I have to get default downloaded location. (reason being we cant modify IE downloaded location)

```
def get_ie_download_path():
    reg = Reg()
    path = 'HKCU\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders'
    downloadregconfig = reg.read_value(path, '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}')
    downloadlocation = downloadregconfig["data"]
    return downloadlocation
```

Using above function i am getting IE Default download location i.e. C:\Users\bnduch\Downloads, But cant use it since it contains '\'. so i am forced to update '\' to '/'.  So that i can REMOVE/Delete the file. This is the code i am using

```
${DownloadDir}=  get_ie_download_path
${DownloadDir}=  Catenate  ${DownloadDir}/Daily Reads Status Report.xlsx
Remove File  ${DownloadDir}
```

Please suggest

Comment: I do not see why you need to convert a single backslash to a double backslash in `${DownloadDir}`. Why do you say _"But cant use it since it contains '\'"_ - what makes you think you can't use it? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the exact error?

Comment: hmm U r Right Bryan. I was Wrong. Its working fine.  Code is able to open the xlsx file.

Comment: My Bad i messed up with two different things. I updated the Question right now with the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems, all related to the fact that the backslash is an escape character.

First, you need to escape the backslashes in `C:\Users\bnduch\Downloads`, ie: `C:\\Users\\bnduch\\Downloads`

Next, you need to do the same with the other two arguments. To get a single backslash use two; to get two, use four:  `\` needs to be `\\` and `\\` needs to be `\\\\`.

Your complete statement should look like this:

```
${location1} =    Replace String    C:\\Users\\bnduch\\Downloads    \\    \\\\
```

With that, `${location1}` will be set to the 28-byte string `C:\\Users\\bnduch\\Downloads`

*All of that being said*, this looks like a code smell. It's very rare that you need to replace backslashes with double backslashes in a file path. If you could show us why you think you need to do this, we can possibly offer better solutions.

Comment: I am trying to get IE default downloading location since we cant change IE downloading folder. I am using this function . (updated in the Q). To use the path i have to update the '\' to '\\'. then will add my file.

Comment: I have updated all the info the Q. Pl suggest if you see any solution

Comment: @bbk: your edits don't require me to change my answer. The problem is that if you have a literal backslash in your test, you need to add a second backslash to escape it.